# Как мне сделать условия с id в javascript

Tags: javascript

Приветствую Уважаемые!
Имеется такой вот не хитрый функционал:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код этого функционала:

```
<section  class="col col-6">
         <label class="toggle">
         <input name="monetizationType" value="rebill" type="radio">
<i data-swchon-text="ВКЛ" data-swchoff-text="ВЫКЛ"></i><h5 id="rebill" class="text-left text-success"><strong>Ребиллы</strong></h5></label>
         <label class="toggle">
         <input name="monetizationType" value="autosell" type="radio">
<i data-swchon-text="ВКЛ" data-swchoff-text="ВЫКЛ"></i><h5 id="autosell" class="text-left text-danger"><strong>Автовыкуп</strong></h5></label>
         <label class="toggle">
         <input name="monetizationType" value="credit" type="radio">
<i data-swchon-text="ВКЛ" data-swchoff-text="ВЫКЛ"></i><h5 id="credit" class="text-left text-danger"><strong>Кредитование</strong></h5></label>
</section>
```

код обработки этих данных:

```
$("#smart-mod-eg1").click(function(e) {
            $.SmartMessageBox({
                title : "Изменение настроек",
                content : "Вы действительно хотите изменить настройки аккаунта?",
                buttons : '[НЕТ][ДА]'
            }, function(ButtonPressed) {
                if (ButtonPressed === "ДА") {
        
 
          var msg   = $('#settingsUpd').serialize();
            $.ajax({
              type: 'POST',
               url: '<?php echo ASSETS_URL; ?>/php/settings.php',
              data: msg,
                        success: function(data) {
            $('#error').html(data);
          },
              error:  function(xhr, str){
            alert('Возникла ошибка: ' + xhr.responseCode + '. Разработчики уже в курсе...');
              }
            });
     
                    $.smallBox({
                        title : "Выполнено",
                        content : "<i class='fa fa-cog'></i> <i>Настройки изменены</i>",
                        color : "#659265",
                        iconSmall : "fa fa-check fa-2x fadeInRight animated",
                        timeout : 5000
                    });
                    
                    $('#rebill').removeClass('text-left text-danger');
                    $('#rebill').addClass('text-left text-success');
                }
                if (ButtonPressed === "НЕТ") {
                    $.smallBox({
                        title : "Не выполнено",
                        content : "<i class='fa fa-cog'></i> <i>Вы отказались от изменения настроек</i>",
                        color : "#C46A69",
                        iconSmall : "fa fa-times fa-2x fadeInRight animated",
                        timeout : 5000
                    });
                }

            });
            e.preventDefault();
        })
```

так вот, в этом куске кода обработчика:

```
$('#rebill').removeClass('text-left text-danger');
$('#rebill').addClass('text-left text-success');
```

удаляется класс, который выделяет красным и добавляется класс, который выделает зеленым текст. Но в данном варианте он делает это только с  id=rebill.
Как правильно сформировать код, чтобы было с условием - если id=rebill в режиме ON, т.е. выбран то делаем то-то, если id=autosell то делаем то-то и т.д.?
Т.е. у меня без перезагрузки изменяются настройки и нужно чтобы без перезагрузки было соответствующее выделение текста цветом.

Благодарю за внимание!

Comment: Уважаемые! Что, никто не может помочь? Нет знаний? Или нет желания помогать?))) Хочу указать на то, что это чисто для себя пишу. Это не коммерческий проект.

Comment: может всё-таки лучше выложить итоговый html без php условий?

Comment: удалил php условия

Comment: Совет - сделайте **минимально**-понятный проблемный участок. А то лень разбираться что там может быть и где конкретно Ваш вопрос.

Comment: мне нужно составить условие правильно, своими словами это условие можно описать так:     если активирован инпут с именем - name="monetizationType"  и значением  - value="rebill"  то  $('#rebill').addClass('text-left text-success');   ну а дальше просто правильно составленное условие повторю три раза.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например, вот так.

```
$("input[type=radio]").change(function(e) {
  var child = $("#" + $(this).val());
  child.removeClass('text-danger').addClass('text-success');
});
```

Comment: поставил код, не работает. Просто ничего не происходит. Может быть такое не реализуемо вообще?

Comment: Не может не работать https://jsfiddle.net/zsmhdkv6/2/

Comment: ну так не работает же) мне показывает в алерте что true, а в коде по прежнему text-left text-danger   вместо   text-left text-success. я нажал на автовыкуп и по идее в этом участке   <h5 id="autosell" class="text-left text-danger">  должен сначала удалиться класс а потом добавиться другой. Но этого не происходит.

Comment: @Кино Трейлеры, ну посмотрите, если не верите https://jsfiddle.net/zsmhdkv6/4/

Comment: так я и посмотрел. Сейчас попробовал и снова ничего не изменилось. Смысл заключается именно в изменении в самом коде. Мне вылетает алерт и всё, а в коде выше в нужном месте название класса никак не изменяется, разве Вы не видите? Я нажимаю на Кредитование, и по идее должен измениться в коде сверху в этом участке кода <h5 id="credit" class="text-left text-danger" класс, т.е. сначала удалиться text-left text-danger, а затем проставиться новый  text-left text-success. Разве не в этом суть кода? А мне просто вылетает алерт и все. А коде нет никаких изменений.

Comment: прошу прощения, действительно работает. Просто именно по Вашей ссылке там не меняется, а через отладчик в браузере хром попробовал и все работает. Хотя в моем коде что указан в вопросе не работает, именно в коде обработки. Придется сделать отдельно.

Comment: Скажите, а как мне теперь доделать немного. Я забыл сразу указать этот момент. Мне нужно чтобы у того, который был активирован до клика и работы данного кода  $("input[type=radio]").change(function(e) {
  var child = $("#" + $(this).val());

  child.removeClass('text-left text-danger');
  child.addClass('text-left text-success');
}); класс менялся на этот text-left text-danger?

Comment: @Кино Трейлеры, в алерт выводится класс элемента, и он меняется. Не несите ерунды. Код страницы средствами js никогда не изменить, учите мат. часть.